# Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: only applying once regardless of how many times are set

Tags: magento-1.9, module, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, free-gift

OK so I'm using C4B Freeproduct extension for this. This basically adds in functionality for you to choose a product as a free gift if certain criteria are met. This adds the functionality directly to the shopping cart price rules promo section.

[image: This is basically what it adds to the shopping cart rules section of the site]

So I don't know why it won't apply a rule more then once, but it only applies it once. The modules observer.php contains this:

```
 /**
 * Make sure that a gift is only added once, create a free item and add it to the cart.
 * 
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $rule
 */   
protected static function _handleGift(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote,
                                      Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item,
                                      Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule $rule) {
    if ($rule->getIsApplied()) {
        return;
    }

    $qty = (integer) $rule->getDiscountAmount();
    if ($qty) {
        $freeItem = self::_getFreeQuoteItem($quote, $rule->getGiftSku(), $item->getStoreId(), $qty);
        self::_addAndApply($quote, $freeItem, $rule);
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to modify this at all to allow a rule follow the Maximimum Qty Discount Applied To Field: but If anyone can help in this it's most appreciated. I have tried for the past 4 days modifying code creating functions and I just keep running into a dead end. Can someone please help here.

Comment: How would you expect this setting to take effect? "Maximum qty" is used for percentage discounts, i.e. "10% off for maximum 5 products". But what should "2 free gifts for maximum 5 products" mean? You either get 2 free gifts, or not. If you are looking for "number of free gifts based on number of ordered items" and then set a limit to that, the extension is not made for this (I know, because I was involved in its development)

Comment: Thats what why im trying to extend this further then what was provided.  Im very new to Magento and all magentos nuances are a little much for me to grasp when i havent fully gone rhrough everything which I currently dpnt have time to do

Comment: I also dont understand why the maximum quantitt couldnt work if implemented. Saying maximum 5 gifts of this gift product allowed per order